# How to stop Magnetic sensor from detecting Metals?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am developing a sensor based application whose main aim is to detect the magnetic field of a electric cable.If there is current flowing in the cable, then it should show some message and when there is no current means it should notify that also.Using the following code, It detects the current but the problem is it also detects metallic field.If anyone knows the solution, please let me know.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
      SensorManager sensorManager;
     // static final int sensor = SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION;

      private Sensor myCompassSensor;
      private TextView outView,tesla1,voltage;
      ImageView light1;
      Vibrator v;
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        outView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        tesla1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tesla);
        light1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.light);
        voltage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.voltage);
        v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // get sensor manager
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        // get compass sensor (ie magnetic field)
        myCompassSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
      }

      // register to listen to sensors
      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, myCompassSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      // unregister
      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this,myCompassSensor);
      }

      // Ignore for now
      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // this check is unnecessary with only one registered sensor
          // but it's useful to know in case you need to add more sensors
         synchronized (this)
         {
          if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
             // int orientation = (int) event.values[0];
              float azimuth = Math.round(event.values[0]);
                float pitch = Math.round(event.values[1]);
                float roll = Math.round(event.values[2]);
                double tesla= Math.sqrt((azimuth*azimuth)+(pitch*pitch)+(roll*roll));

                String out = String.format("X: %.2f\nY: %.2f\nZ: %.2f",
                    azimuth, pitch, roll);
                String a=String.format("%2f", tesla);
                Log.d("MAGENTIC---", out);
               // outView.setText(out);
                tesla1.setText(a);
                if(tesla>=80)
                {
                    v.vibrate(200);
                    light1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.voltage_on);
                    voltage.setText("Voltage Detected !");
                }
                else
                {
                light1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.voltage_off);
                voltage.setText("No Voltage Found");
                }
    }
          else
              return;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Metallic field".  What's that then?  I think you mean the magnetic field generated by ferrous metals - which will look the the same as the magnetic field surrounding a live cable to the sensor in your phone.  You need far more sophisticated sensors to distinguish between them.  So no.

Comment: @Simon : Thanks for your answer.I am not aware about the fields which creates magnetic field.Does metals also create magnetic field ?

Comment: No, only ferrous metals.

Answer (score 3):

If you are detecting an (AC) alternating current/signal, then over even a very short time, you should see a signal that varies in amplitude and polarity. You could sample and store a number of readings and detect this is happening. In the case of a steady magnetic field, the readings should also be steady. You should be able to develop an algorithm to seperate these different cases.

If you are detecting a steady state DC current, this may not help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware, the update rate of the phone could be as low as 50ms, or 20Hz.
If we assume that the measurements are 'sample and hold' averages and the AC frequency is 60Hz (depends on where you live), you would have exactly three periods per sample, cancelling out to no signal. If your sample time instead is 58ms you would have 3.5 periods which would produce a signal. Hence - there is a good chance that you could infer if the magnetic field is alternating by looking at your sampled data.

One way to do so is simply calculating the variance of your data. Otherwise you could apply a digital high-pass filter to ignore slower changing fields.